# Why is index faster than pop in python list?

Tags: python, time-complexity

Hello I'm practice coding test on leetcode and I have one question.

"26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array" description is as below.

Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that each element appears only once and returns the new length. Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

**Solution 01**

```
# 4.4948496559999995
idx = 0
for _ in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[-1-idx] == nums[-2-idx]:
        nums.pop(-1-idx)
    else:
        idx += 1
return len(nums)
```

**Solution 02**

```
# 3.689027874
ans = 1
for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] != nums[i+1]:
        nums[ans] = nums[i+1]
        ans += 1
return ans
```

**Check Time Complexity**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("for t in [[1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], []]: Solution().removeDuplicates(t)", "from __main__ import Solution")
print(t.timeit())
```

Solution 01 running time was 4.4948496559999995 and Solution 02 running time was 3.689027874

pop and index have O(1) time complexity but why is solution 02 faster than solution 01 ?

Comment: object attribute lookup, and function call overhead...

Comment: Are `nums` the same size at the end?

Comment: `pop` is O(1) *if you're popping the last element*.

Comment: Note your problem statement is about *memory* complexity not *time* complexity

Comment: Also your solution 2 is leaving a bunch of garbage at the end of the list - you have to remove that garbage. (A slice deletion would be appropriate.)

Comment: You checked time, not time complexity. And the big-O doesn't tell you that a O(n) action is slower than an O(1) in some specific case, only how the time needed will evolve relatively to the size of your data.

Comment: About `pop`, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity indicates: "[2] = Popping the intermediate element at index k from a list of size n shifts all elements after k by one slot to the left using memmove. n - k elements have to be moved, so the operation is O(n - k). The best case is popping the second to last element, which necessitates one move, the worst case is popping the first element, which involves n - 1 moves. The average case for an average value of k is popping the element the middle of the list, which takes O(n/2) = O(n) operations."

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I am sure about leetcode is that the running time does not equal the time complexity of your algorithm. Sometimes it depends on when you are submitting it and how busy the website is. Once I submitted the same answer three times and every time got a different running time.